# Filter a multidimensional array - filter_array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, filter

How do you filter this multidimensional array with `array_filter()` based on `[channel]`?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [268a9d2d25fc2b9765c7cd7b8a768d3e] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => Emilian
                    [show_name] => TechnoShow
                    [channel] => techno
                    [show_image] => http://www.digitalark.ro/dieselfm/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/avatar.jpg
                    [time] => 0
                    [time_end] => 1
                    [sun1] => 1
                    [sun2] => 1
                    [sun3] => 1
                    [sun4] => 1
                    [sun5] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [e13268de7c56db42f8aeab2ab4c607f2] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => John Doe
                    [show_name] => John Doe`s Trance Show
                    [channel] => trance
                    [show_image] => http://www.digitalark.ro/dieselfm/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/dummy.jpg
                    [time] => 11
                    [time_end] => 11
                    [mon1] => 1
                    [mon2] => 1
                    [tue2] => 1
                    [mon3] => 1
                    [fri3] => 1
                    [mon4] => 1
                    [mon5] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Results should have only the arrays that have the value "techno", for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [268a9d2d25fc2b9765c7cd7b8a768d3e] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => Emilian
                    [show_name] => TechnoShow
                    [channel] => techno
                    [show_image] => http://www.digitalark.ro/dieselfm/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/avatar.jpg
                    [time] => 0
                    [time_end] => 1
                    [sun1] => 1
                    [sun2] => 1
                    [sun3] => 1
                    [sun4] => 1
                    [sun5] => 1
                )

        ))
```

I have tried using:

```
$data = array_filter($dataraw, function($fs) use ($genre) {return $fs['channel'] == $genre});
```

EDIT:

```
$djs = get_posts($args);
foreach ($djs as $dj) {
    $temp = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($dj->ID, 'show_data',true));
    if ($temp) $show_data[] = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($dj->ID, 'show_data',true));
}


$datax = array_filter($show_data, function($fs) use ($genre) {
 return array_values($fs)[0]['channel'] == $genre;
});

print_r($datax);
```

Comment: `return array_values($fs)[0]['channel'] == $genre;`

Comment: this print_r`s out : "Array ( )" hmm  ... ill also add the context in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the parse error in your code was a copy/paste mistake.  The problem is that the element passed into the function is a deeper array.  Try:

```
return current($fs)['channel'] === $genre;
```

Also you might want to use `===` so the results are as expected.

Comment: Thank you ... it worked  ... i`ve been racking my head on this for a whole day :) ... im so green at php.